# django-allauth and changing Facebook app ID

Tags: django-allauth

Does anybody know what will happen to my existing users when I will change Facebook app ID in allauth (socialauth) configuration?

Will "login with FB" try to create new django accounts or will it just log users in to existing ones (and obviously, asking via FB for permission)?

I'm in a situation where I have large amount of users signed up using FB but now I'm forced to create new FB app and switching to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have checked it out. The answer is yes, users will fall into the signup flow instead of being logged in.

It's because Facebook assigns app-scoped ID to users. An app doesn't know user's original ID, it gets user's ID generated especially for this app. For this reason django-allauth won't recognize existing FB users (from previous FB app).